# Xcode git not showing xcassets to commit

Tags: xcode, git

Here is what I did.

1. Change the image names in xcassets folder.
2. Try to commit.Then get an error message like this.'

[image]

3. Try committing a few more times
4. Quit xcode, reopen xcode
5. Clean & Build
6. Click source control then click commit and see "No file was changed"

So now my images have different names but on bitbucket they are still the old way.
I then opened terminal and wrote git status and it returned "nothing to commit, working directory clean", I also can't commit with terminal.

How can I resolve this problem.
I want the image names to be the same in bitbucket version.

Answer (score 1):

Very late but I had a similar problem as your 6th step, and I guess there's a good chance it's the same source.

Even in command line, `git diff` wouldn't allow me to see the changes on may `.xcassets` folder.

Somehow I was able to add the files to commit with

`git commit -a`

then push, and everything went well.

You may also try

`git add /path/to/the/file/or/folder`

if you don't want to add all modified files to your commit, then

`git commit`